# Can I use the curly brace syntax to concatenate the text of a text node in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I only recently learned about the curly brace syntax in XSLT, which allows to specify an XPath expression where a string is expected, and its usefulness to concatenate strings.

So, in my XSLT, I replaced all instances of

```
<entry>
    <xsl:attribute name="id" select="concat(@artifactId, '-', @version, '.zip')" />
</entry>
```

with the much shorter

```
<entry id="{@artifactId}-{@version}.zip" />
```

So far so good. But now I was wondering if I could use the same syntax to concatenate the text for a text node.

Example:

```
<sourceLocation>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($baseURL, '/artifacts/', @artifactId, '-', @version, '.zip')" />
</sourceLocation>
```

Is there a way to generate this text node using the curly brace syntax instead of `concat` in standard XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, XSLT 3.0 allows it however, with a setting http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#text-value-templates, and some implementation like Saxon 9.5 PE or EE already support that:

```
<sourceLocation>{$baseURL}/artifacts/{@artifactId}-{@version}.zip</sourceLocation>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not in XSLT 2.0, but it will be possible in XSLT 3.0, where the syntax is referred to as "[text value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#text-value-templates)" (akin to attribute value templates).